# javascript function not being called on text box but only on Save (for validation group)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have text box with datepicker and a custom validator under validation group meant for a Save button at the end of a web page. The problem is the javascrip function is being called on Save but not on this text box value change. What am I doing wrong?

Text Box:

```
<td valign="middle">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassingDate" runat="server" Width="106px" Text='<%# Bind("PassingDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <img style="width: 17px; height: 16px" id="IMG1" onclick="javascript:calendarPicker('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassingDate');"
                alt="Select Date" src="../Images/show-calendar.gif" border="0" />
        </td>
```

Validator:

```
  <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="valCusRangePassingDate" ValidationGroup="Save"
                Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtPassingDate" ClientValidationFunction="CompareDateRange"
                ErrorMessage="Only last three months reimbursement is allowed" ForeColor="Red"
                Font-Bold="False"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Note: There are other custom vlidator JS functions also associated with the same text box.
The Save button on which currently my JS is being called:

```
  <asp:Button ID="Save" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="Save_Click" ValidationGroup="Save"
                OnClientClick="return  ConfirmSave()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Client Side validation check in your TextBox value change event.

```
function textbox_change()
{
    if(Page_ClientValidate('Save'))
    {
        //Your Code
    }
    else
    {
       //your code
    }
}
```

`Page_ClientValidate` is function for validation from client side. you can pass your validation group as a parameter.

Comment: But I have a similar textbox with similar conditions ..i.e having a custom validator under Save group but still the validation works on entry in the textbox without having to click Save button.How come it is working there?

Comment: if you have any other textbox with similar validationGroup then you can give another name of validationGroup for this client side event. It will definately work...

Comment: But then on Save also if I wish to once again confirm for this textbox then?

Comment: you have to customize js according to your validation call. this is just the idea which I have shown you...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your asp.net control does not see the change when your control is manipulated by the datepicker. Adding this code should solve your problem:

```
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            onSelect: function () {
                this.fireEvent && this.fireEvent('onchange') || $(this).change();
            }
        });
    });
 </script>


 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassingDate" runat="server" Width="106px" CssClass="datepicker" Text='<%# Bind("PassingDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

This will fire the onChange event of your control when the datepicker value is selected. This example is using the actual jQueryUI datepicker, which is probably much better and easier to use than the CalendarPicker you are using.

Comment: Oh..yes..I tried manipulating date in text box..then the JS was hit.COuld you please explain your solution..and I should add this to my aspx or the js file? :(..

Comment: I copied the same at the end f my aspx page un the script tag..still not working..where should I put I put it..or any modifications in the code required..and this one is generic

Comment: I should write calendarPicker ..instead of datePicker?and function shuld be replcaed by my function name?

Comment: It is going to go in your aspx page in a script tag. This is assuming that you are using the latest jQuery library. All you need to do is give your input a cssClass of 'datepicker' and it should work. You can remove the 'onclick' event code of your input as it is not needed.

Comment: What if we are not..any alternative?

Comment: If you aren't using the latest jQuery, or even one that is reasonably new, you may experience problems with your javascript and it may not work or give weird/unexpected results in certain browsers/scenarios depending on what they are. There are many different ways to acquire these, you can either download them or reference them from the Google API like I am in the example above. It doesn't have to be the very latest, but at least reasonably new...